# How to get SumoSelect Selected values in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sumoselect.js

I am using the [SumoSelect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) dropdown for multi selection options. But I cannot get the selected values array in PHP. I am getting **NULL** when I **var_dump** the data.. Below is the code that what I have done so far..

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<select name="industry[]" id="industry" style="width:305px;" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Choose Industry" class="SlectBox">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected>-- Choose Industry<span style="color:red; margin-left:2px;">*</span>  -- </option>
    <option value="Agriculture & Food">Agriculture & Food</option>
    <option value="Apparel, Textiles & Accessories">Apparel, Textiles & Accessories</option>
    <option value="Auto & Tranportation">Auto & Tranportation</option>
    <option value="Bags, Shoes & Accessories">Bags, Shoes & Accessories</option>
    <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
    <option value="Electrical Equipment, Components & Telecoms">Electrical Equipment, Components & Telecoms</option>
    <option value="Gifts, Sports & Toys">Gifts, Sports & Toys</option>
    <option value="Health & Beauty">Health & Beauty</option>
    <option value="Home, Lights & Construction">Home, Lights & Construction</option>
    <option value="Machinery, Industrial Parts & Tools">Machinery, Industrial Parts & Tools</option>
    <option value="Metallurgy, Chemicals, Rubber & Plastic">Metallurgy, Chemicals, Rubber & Plastic</option>
    <option value="Packaging, Advertising & Office">Packaging, Advertising & Office</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            window.asd = $('.SlectBox').SumoSelect({ csvDispCount: 3 });
        });
 </script>
```

**PHP**

```
$values = $_POST['industry'];
var_dump($values);
```

But When I **`var_dump`** I am getting the **`NULL`**. I don't know what is the problem. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that select box inside form tags?

Comment: Can you show the code for the `<form>`?

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/rv5ps0r3/3/ it might going to help!!

Comment: @Matt yes it is inside the form tag..

Comment: @PraveenKumar it is already inside the <form> tag,,

Comment: @BilalAhmed Don't you understand the question? How have you written the form tag, kindly paste the code. Just the starting tag with the attributes will do.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks for your reply.. Please check now I updated my question with <form> tag.. Thanks..

Comment: @BilalAhmed Is both the form and the `var_dump` are in the same page?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes.It is on the same page..

Comment: @BilalAhmed Okay this is crazy. Single PHP file na, can you post the full code by **[edit]ing** your question?

Comment: Try changing the `<select>` tag's `name` attribute to just `industry` (no square brackets).

Comment: @PraveenKumar when I did not use the SumoSelect (means without above Javascript code) then var_dump shows the values but when I use the SumoSelect it is giving the NULL..

Comment: @BilalAhmed I am not sure if this helps. Check out this issue: https://github.com/HemantNegi/jquery.sumoselect/issues/51

Comment: @PraveenKumar the code is very lengthy.. Is it good to paste full code here so that it did not mess.. ??

Comment: @BilalAhmed No if needed. But before that, kindly check out the link that I have sent to you and see if it is any good.

Comment: @PraveenKumar the link you provided did not help me.. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Sorry man, then have you hosted it somewhere, so that we can see it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar can you please suggest me where should I host..

Comment: Somewhere, free hosting or something?

Comment: @PraveenKumar free hosting.

Comment: Google is your friend! `:)`

Comment: @BilalAhmed I don't think you need to host your PHP also. Just use http://jsbin.com and put your code. We'll take care of the replication to PHP later.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I uploaded the file on google drive kindly check it.. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Xt4Jgo0jKHbHNPTlZ1bG5BZFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I said to use http://jsbin.com and **replicate the issue**. Just the HTML please.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I never use jsbin.com. So I don't know how to use it.. Thanks for your reply. Please help me out I need this to be sorted as soon as possible.

Comment: @BilalAhmed Kindly try and learn it man. It is easy.

Comment: @PraveenKumar PHP is not supported anymore in jsbin.com

Comment: I just said you **Just use the HTML please**. We don't need PHP for now. @BilalAhmed.

Comment: @BilalAhmed. Okay, understand, the issue is with HTML. Not the PHP.

Comment: @PraveenKumar kindly check it.. http://jsbin.com/yebemu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @BilalAhmed Nice. Which exact form is having the SumoSelect?

Comment: @PraveenKumar.. Sorry I did not understand...